# Artificially limited ostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm writing an object serialization library that couples to std::ostreams.  Depending on the underlying streambuf, some ostreams support seek operations and some don't.  Additionally, some streams write to a fixed-size sink and some will grow (fstream, stringstream, etc.).

In my case, I'm working on an embedded system, and I want to be very protective of my resources.  I would like to impose an arbitrary maximum limit on the number of bytes I am allowed to write, in a stream-independent manner.

I've written custom streambufs before (one wrapping zlib, one wrapping the sqlite blob api).  I suppose I could write another custom wrapping streambuf just for this limiting purpose.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?  If I have to write another streambuf, is there a trivial way to keep count of number of actual bytes written to the underlying stream?

Limitations:
can't use boost (embedded platform)
should work for any standard ostream (fstream, stringstream, cout, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to implement your own `streambuf::overflow`, and return EOF if the limit is reached.

Comment: I think the standard only guarantees that overflow will be called when an actual overflow situation occurs.  I think I would need eof to be returned immediately when a call to write is made, rather than waiting for an overflow situation?

Comment: Why do you care about limiting output when it fits in the existing buffer? If you make the initial buffer small, overflow gets called "early". I did something similar some time back [can't remember exactly what it was we were trying to achieve, but I remember working using overflow to do some work, and having a buffer of one byte].

Comment: My concern is that overflow is called when the underlying backing store is full.  Assume I have a 1000 byte limit imposed by my custom streambuf, which has a 128 byte backing store.  I can write 999 bytes, flush, and then write another 127 bytes before overflow is called again.  I'd like for any write operation to the underlying stream to fail fast before my artificial limit is reached.
If I don't use a backing buffer, will I still have the efficiencies of the buffering in the underlying ostream?  Or will my wrapper stream effectively force everything into single-byte writes?

Comment: Well, if you want absolute limits, rather than "per lump" limits, then I suppose you'll have to add some accounting somewhere else in your streambuf implementation - not entirely sure how you'd do that, as it's not something I have done.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  The goal is to have the stream fail before any data is written to the underlying ostream.  That way I have the opportunity to check for failbit or badbit at the top level and direct the data elsewhere if possible.  (like log rotation, for example, although that's not my use case).

Comment: Marking this as fixed, because I believe this is what I am limited to.  I have no guarantee that all streams in a chain of streams are capable of accurately providing stream position, as each can have its own buffer.  Furthermore, streams that perform transformations (compression, formatting) have no way to inform upstream callers whether a write will overflow a downstream buffer before it happens.